# Determining the ideal number of clusters by comparing the agglomeration coefficients of severel cluster numbers. Cluster-Analysis

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, dendrogram

I am currently stuck at a cluster-analysis. I would like to determine the ideal number of clusters by comparing the agglomerative coefficients of different number of clusters to each other. The percentage change in coefficient to the next level should be the basis for my decision, like in the following screenshot:

[Percentage Change in Coefficient to next level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvrEm.png)

But I do not know how to get these coefficients. I was only able to compute the AC for the whole dendrogram by using the AGNES program. How can I get the agglomeration coefficient for different numbers of clusters?

I'll appreciate an advice, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `coef.hclust()` in R?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. For general model fitting questions rather than programming questions, you would be better off asking for help at [stats.se]

Comment: @DavidZ yes, I did. But this gives me the coefficient for the whole dendrogram. I would like to have an option which let me choose the cluster number with the respective coefficient as outcome.

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks for the hint, I moved the question over to StackExchange